# Can I override VueJS built-in directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-directives

I want to add an `important` modifier to the `v-show` directive. I copied it's code and added the modifier.

**Can I somehow override the built-in `v-show` directive?** I tried:

```js
import { vShow } from "@/directives/vShow"
...
const app = createApp(App).
    directive("show", vShow)
    ...
    mount("#app")
```

but it doesn't work. Vue still uses the built-in one. It works if I register it as a new directive (`v-cshow`):

```
const app = createApp(App).
    directive("cshow", vShow).
    ...
    mount("#app")
```

Comment: What style are you trying to overwrite with `!important`?

Comment: @bassxzero `d-flex` class from Vuetify has `display: flex !important`. But basically any UI lib uses `!important` on utility classes. I saw there is a issue and a PR for adding `important`  modifier to the `v-show` directive but they don't want to implement it. So I decided to create my own directive and hopefully override the default one.

Comment: How about creating an issue on github.com/vue/core?

Comment: I doubt this is possible by design on Vue's part. I had a browse online and saw that a workaround is using `*[style*="display: none"] { display: none !important }`, which will apply the `!important` flag to all v-show elements